# how to animate jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

hello im using this code to load content from another php file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           setInterval(function(){
                               $('.live-stream ul').each(function(){
                                    $(this).load('tx.php');
                        });
                }, 1000);

        });
```

this works correctly but i want script to fadeIn each "li" when a new record added, anyone?

the thing i want to do is something like facebook's live user action feed that on the right top of facebook home

Comment: You could use `display:none` or `opacity:0` in the CSS and do a regular jQuery animation.

Answer (score 20):

You have to hide it first.

```
$(this).hide().load("tx.php").fadeIn('500');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
        $('.live-stream ul').each(function(){
           $(this).hide().load('tx.php').fadeIn('500');
        });
     }, 1000);

});
```

Note the use of `fadeIn()` and `hide()`... You don't need hide if you already have the `<li>`'s hidden.

Comment: That's because you used the `.live-steam ul` selector. You're selecting each li and doing it at the same time. Were you looking for a different effect?

Answer (score 1):

what if you call the fadeIn method

```
$(this).load('tx.php').fadeIn(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

call handler while loading

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
         $('.live-stream ul').each(function(){
                $(this).load('tx.php', function(){
                         $('li').fadeIn("normal");
                            });
                 });
        }, 1000);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me without any issues of content flickering:

```
const pageLink = '/...'
const $container = $("#page-content")
$container.hide().load(pageLink, () => {
    $container.fadeIn(500)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this one?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.live-stream ul').each(function(){
            $(this).load('tx.php').fadeIn('1000');
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

hmmm, what about this one

```
$(function(){
//Fade in all objects.
var wrapper = $("live-stream ul");
$(wrapper).hide();

function fadeInAll(elem, fadeInTime, timeBetween)
{
    for(i=0; i<elem.size(); i++)
    {
        $(elem[i]).delay(i*(timeBetween+fadeInTime)).fadeIn(fadeInTime);    
    }
}

fadeInAll($(wrapper), 1000, 500);

});
```

Comment: hmm, i have tried my 2nd code, that work for me, but i don't know if that work too for ya

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is shown before the .fadeIn("1000") will be executed. First you have to hide the selected element, load the content and then fadeIn, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
       $('.live-stream ul').each(function(){
           $(this).hide().load('tx.php').fadeIn("1000");
       });
   }, 1000);

});
```

Or hide the elements with css:

```
display: none;
```

EDIT:
Should be something like this, but it's not tested...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
       var streamListElement = $(document.createElement("li")).load('tx.php').hide();
       $('.live-stream ul').append( streamListElement ).find(":hidden").fadeIn("3000");
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: when i do this all li's are blinking every 1 second

Comment: @Ronnie Chester Lynwood Thats because of your setInterval(). You call the function every second ;) What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: im trying to do something like facebook's live user action feed that on the right top of facebook home

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback but hide the li using CSS `display: none;` fadeIn should work after that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
         $('.live-stream ul').each(function(){
                $(this).load('tx.php', function(){
                         $(this).find('li').fadeIn();
                            });
                 });
        }, 1000);

    });
```

Comment: is there any way to use setInterval for only li's not whole ul?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use animation directly on load(). But here is the trick I used:

```
$("#id").animate({opacity: 0},1000);
$("#id").load(url);
$("#id").animate({opacity: 1},1000);
```

The element doesn't display, just becomes transparent. It looks just the same.